# Assigning symbolic variables to numeric variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I have symbolic variables which are:

```
[q dq ddq n]

q=[q1; q2];
dq=[dq1; dq2];
ddq=[ddq1; ddq2];
```

and  variable `n` is

```
 n=[2*dq1 + (83*dq1*dq2)/400;
   (83*dq1^2)/800 + 2*dq2]
```

I'm trying to obtain the values of an ODE function using the variables:

```
state=[q; dq];
u=[5;5];

q1=state(1);
q2=state(2);
dq1=state(3);
dq2=state(4);

dxdt1=dq1;
dxdt2=dq2;
ddxdt=inv(B)*(u-n);  %which is 2x1 matrix
                     %B is a 2x2 numeric matrix
dstate=[dxdt1; dxdt2; ddxdt];
```

using this variables I try to obtain the solution of the equation

```
t0=0;
tf=1;
N=10;
tspan=linspace(t0,tf,N);

x0=[0.5; 0.5;zeros(2,1)];
function_q=@(tspan,state)ode_system(tspan,state,B,n,u);
```

where odesystem is

```
function dydt=ode_system(time, state,B,n_t,u)
q1=state(1);
q2=state(2);
dq1=state(3);
dq2=state(4);

dxdt1=dq1;
dxdt2=dq2;
ddxdt=inv(B)*(u-n_t);
dydt=[dxdt1; dxdt2; ddxdt]

end
```

at the end I try to calculate

```
[tout,xout]=ode45(function_q, tspan, x0)
```

when I run the code it gives an error and say

> Error using odearguments (line 110) Inputs must be floats, namely
>   single or double.
>
> Error in ode45 (line 115)
>       odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode,
>       tspan, y0, options, varargin);
>
> Error in mainfunc (line 140) [tout,xout]=ode45(function_q, tspan, x0) 
>   try open('Error using odearguments (line 110)
>             ↑ Error: String is not terminated properly.

I think the problem is resulted from to put symbolic variable to ode45 function. How can I solve this problem? How can I define n matrix in numerical form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the type of the return value from `ode_system`. Because `n_t` is symbolic, `dydt` is symbolic and `ode45` doesn't like that. Within `ode_system`, try using `subs` to replace the variables in `n_t` with their corresponding values. And then use `double` to convert the symbolic number to a "regular" number. This will be slow if you make a bigger system, but it should be fine for now.

```
function dydt=ode_system(time, state,B,n_t,u)
q1=state(1);
q2=state(2);
dq1=state(3);
dq2=state(4);

dxdt1=dq1;
dxdt2=dq2;
free_vars = sym({'dq1','dq2'});
free_values = [dq1,dq2];
n_t = subs(n_t, free_vars, free_values);
n_t = double(n_t);
ddxdt=inv(B)*(u-n_t);
dydt=[dxdt1; dxdt2; ddxdt]

end
```